# failwith in the explicit object constructor using F#

Tags: class, object, types, f#, constructor

The following code

```
type A (b) =
  new () =
    if true then A 4.
    else failwith ""
```

gives an error:

> This is not a valid object construction expression. Explicit object constructors must either call an alternate constructor or initialize all fields of the object and specify a call to a super class constructor.

This works:

```
type A (b) =
  new () =
    if true then A 4.
    else failwith ""; A 4.
```

Simple question. What is so bad about `failwith` in the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is not specific to `failwith`; it would also occur with any other expression of type `A` other than a constructor call, such as `Unchecked.defaultof<A>`.  As the error message indicates, constructors have restrictions on the kinds of expressions that can be used within them to ensure that types are always initialized soundly.

As I mentioned in a comment on Daniel's answer, if you want to fail fast in certain cases you could do something like:

```
new() =
    if true then failwith ""
    A 4.0
```

This will throw an exception before it gets a chance to execute the chained constructor call.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not `failwith` per se. As the error indicates, non-primary constructors are restricted. This is to encourage putting all initialization logic in the primary constructor. Your example seems contrived. If you show more of what you're trying to do perhaps someone can offer a solution.

Here's one way to rework your code:

```
type A (b) =
  new () = A(4.0) then 
    if true then failwith ""
```

`then` acts like a `do` binding in non-primary constructors.

See the MSDN page on [Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx) for more options.

#### EDIT

kvb made a good point regarding primary constructors with side effects. If that's the case you may want to consider moving your logic to a static method. This makes it obvious that other work may be done prior to calling the constructor.

```
type A (b) =
  static member Create() =
    if true then failwith ""
    else A(4.0)
```

Comment: I like your workaround, but it probably makes sense to throw first, then call the primary constructor (in case the constructor has side effects).

Comment: You can actually use my suggested order within a constructor, not just a static method: `if true then failwith ""` on one line then `A 4.` on the next.

Comment: Oldrich mentioned that's a workable approach in his question. I thought I might mention using a static method since it makes the process flow a bit more obvious (IMO). I like to use additional constructors only for overloading.

Comment: I don't see it in the question, but maybe I'm just missing something...  In his example he uses an `if/then/else`, not an `if/then`, and calls a constructor in both branches.

Comment: True. I equated the two. It's probably worth adding an example to your answer, since your approach makes it more obvious that side effects are allowed prior to forwarding to another constructor. I remember really appreciating that when I first discovered it, since doing something similar in C# requires a static method, etc. Definitely worth mentioning.